# Testing Azure Notification Hub without an app

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I have a backend which uses the Notification Hub to send push notifications to an app, however, the app is currently in production and I've been forbidden to test my code against it to ensure it works unless as a last resort.

I set up a new Azure account to test my code against, but as it has no applications on it, it throws an error if I try testing against it.

I'm wondering if there's any alternatives to testing this, or if it's going to come down to creating a bare bones app to register & test against.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can segregate your traffic in Notification Hubs, but you're going to need an app to send to in order to test your app. You can create a new hub in your existing namespace for these test messages, but you'll need an app configured to use that for testing. We have customers who setup Production and Integration environments specifically for this purpose.